# Visual Studio 2015: Unable to reference Bing Maps library

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, winjs, bing-maps

I'm developing a javascript/html application for WP8.1 [WinJS 4.3/ HTML] in Visual Studio Community 2015 and now I'm at the part of implementing the map.

Unfortunately I seem to be unable to reference the javascript api (bing ajax)... Seems like implementing this in my pivot item doesn't get the library properly (not at all to be more specific) Following the steps here  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427624.aspx to download the library from the server:

```
<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
```

Fails to reference it and using "Microsoft." namespace ends in error.

So I've tried to install the bing maps extension for VS, which gets installed, but I cannot add the reference to the extension in my VS2015 Community. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ms-appx:///Bing.Maps.JavaScript//js/veapicore.js"></script>
```

But that is again without any success.

So I'm stuck without the library and any map. Any chance there would be an offline version of the bing maps javascript api I could download and reference the same way as WinJS.

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered on the Bing Maps blog and was a topic at the Microsoft //Build/ conference this year. Here is the video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Best-of-Build-2015-Cloud/Visualizing-Business-Data-on-any-Device-with-Bing-Maps

Here is a blog post: https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/06/28/cross-platform-development-with-bing-maps-and-phonegap/

Basically, you will need to use the web URL:

```
<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
```

But you when you go to load the  map you will need to wait for the Microsoft namespace to become available. Alternatively load the map on the document.body.onload event. Here is how you can wait for the Microsoft namespace before loading the map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;

        function getMap()
        {
            var mapElement = document.getElementById('myMap');

            if (typeof Microsoft == 'undefined' ||
                typeof Microsoft.Maps == 'undefined' ||
                mapElement == null) {
                setTimeout(getMap, 100);
                return;
            }

            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(mapElement, { credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key' });
        }

        getMap();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still seeing the error :I'm still getting this error. 
"APPHOST9601: Can't Load <https://evn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0>. An app can't load remote web content in the local context."
even though I allow that specific URL in the <ApplicationContextUriRules> in the application manifest. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you creating a WP8.1 Apache Cordova app in VS2015 or a Universal Windows app? The above works with Cordova perfectly. For universal apps security prevents this from happening. A way around this is to use an iframe as shown in this code sample: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Mashup-Sample-10689f5b

Comment: Here is an article that goes with the code sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh452745?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Hi, I'm using the later, UWP. And thus I've ended up using the webview but I'm having some image tiles being blurred issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662723/webview-bing-map-tiles-appear-to-be-blurred-compared-to-google-maps-ones

Comment: but I still consider it very strange that I cannot use Bing Map API directly in UWP applications. It's Microsoft on both ends and we are forced to use webviews or iframe... showing something on the map is now quite painful due to the very limited option of communicating between the app and the webview/iframe.

Comment: Majority of UWP apps being created are native (c#, VB, C++). There has been little demand for WinJS support on our end.

Comment: @rbrundritt, that seems to be the goal with UWP, all Native no JS. Getting to JS examples and code is difficult now as the "Develop for windows 10" only shows native options. To get to JS API's and examples you end up on "Windows 8.1" which is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The example you posted still seems like it's designed for web page use so it's referencing external JS files.

With windows apps if you ever have to call a JS file it can never be external, so if you ever see an example that has src="http://..." know it wont work or you will have to download it local.

Try this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852186.aspx

It switches to all local references.

That article has a complete example too which helped me get my version working.

Now if they only ported the offline maps option...